# Integrate over `DiracDelta` function, contradiction or my mistake?

Tags: numerical-integration

`DiracDelta` function is an [even function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Properties), therefore I will assume:
$$
1 = \int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}dx \delta(x) = 2\int_0^\epsilon dx \delta(x)
$$

Put these into `mathematica 10` I get:

```
a = 10^-10;
Integrate[DiracDelta[x], {x, -a, a}]
2 Integrate[DiracDelta[x], {x, 0, a}]
(*1*)
(*2 HeavisideTheta[0]*)
```

Unless `HeavisideTheta[0]=1/2` is defined, this is a seemingly contradiction.

Comment: Since the DiracDelta function isn't actually a function but a distribution, this can lead to the wrong intuition when thinking too much of it as a function. The behaviour in your second example is actually on purpose and mentioned under Possible Issues in the documentation. I think it's actually the best possible answer i would expect to this kind of question from `Integrate`. You can define a specific value for `HeavisideTheta[0]`,  if you know this gives a reasonable result for your problem, but since it's a singular distribution it could lead to all kinds of problems in general.

Comment: this is really more of a math question.. see here  http://math.stackexchange.com/a/123249/92921

Comment: Indeed, generically: `Integrate[DiracDelta[x] f[x], {x, -t, t}, Assumptions -> t > 0] ==
 
 2 Integrate[DiracDelta[x] f[x], {x, 0, t}, Assumptions -> t > 0]` evaluates to `f[0] == 2 f[0] HeavisideTheta[0]`.